# My wolves won't stand up again

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was playing in my world and told my pet wolves to sit, some minutes later I closed the game, then, when I reopened it, I could not stand up my wolves again, they got stuck in their place. Tried feeding them, punching them and restart the game but none of these worked.

**Minecraft Version:** 1.10.2

**Mods:** Yes (Forge-Xaero's Minimap, Optifine)

**Game Mode:** Single Player

**Connection:** Connected to Internet

PS: Also tried logging off/on (in same account), disabling internet connection and playing without mods, but none of these could make it work.

Comment: Try breaking the block they are standing on

Comment: I'm having this same issue, but on 1.17.1 with Optifabric.

Answer (score 2):

You could do what Daniel G said and break the block that they're standing on. If that doesn't work, since it seems like you tried everything, I would suggest reporting a bug on the bug tracker for Minecraft.

Here's the link: [Bug Tracker](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC)